# Cordova Android display Base64 encoded PDF in browser

Tags: android, cordova, base64, cordova-plugins, pdf.js

What would be the simplest way to render a PDF document whose Base64 encoding is returned from a web service on an Android app built using cordova?

Can this be done without additional plugins?

Any sample code would be useful.

Comment: Decode the base64 and save the bytes to file. You then have a pdf file. Use Intent.ACTION_VIEW to let the user choose an installed pdf viewer.

Comment: I am using Cordova, so working with HTML/JS code. Is there any way to do it using HTML/JS?

Comment: Why you don't use [File plugin](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/index.html) , and like @greenapps says you will open it with an installed PDF viewer ?